# Java exception javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch when decrypting

Tags: java, kotlin, exception, cryptography, aes-gcm

I am getting javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
There is surely some small detail I am missing out. Thank you in advance!!
Full stack trace:
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:620)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2168)
at crypto.CryptoCore.c3andC4(CryptoCore.java:61)
at PokusMain.main(PokusMain.java:197)

I am sending ciphertext from Kotlin app to Java app. When I try to decrypt the exception occurs.

ciphertext from Kotlin app:

```
fun getFinalCipher(): String {
        //generating key from some parameters
        var ukeyString = hash(appParameters.userKey + "user" + userCryptogram.nonce.toString() +
                receiverCryptogram.nonce.toString(), "SHA-1")
        if (ukeyString != null) {
            ukeyString = ukeyString!!.substring(0,16)
        }
        val command = "unlock"
        val ukey: SecretKey = SecretKeySpec(ukeyString!!.toByteArray(), "AES")
        val parameterSpec = GCMParameterSpec(128, getUserIv()) //IV has the length of 12
        val cipherC3 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
        cipherC3.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ukey, parameterSpec)
        val plaintext = appParameters.atu + command.toByteArray()
        var ciphertext = cipherC3.doFinal(plaintext)
        val ciphertextHex = ciphertext.toHex()
        return ciphertextHex
    }
```

and when I try to decrypt it in Java app:

```
public void c3andC4(String ciphertextHex) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException {
        byte[] ciphertext = decodeHexString(ciphertextHex);
        String userKey = hash(obuParameters.getDriverKey() + userCryptogram.getHatu(), "SHA-1");
        String ukeyString = hash(userKey + "user" + userCryptogram.getNonce() + receiverCryptogram.getNonce(),"SHA-1");
        userKey= userKey.substring(0, 16);
        ukeyString = ukeyString.substring(0,16);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        SecretKey ukey = new SecretKeySpec(ukeyString.getBytes(),"AES");
        GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, userCryptogram.getIv()); //IV has the length of 12
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,ukey, parameterSpec);
        byte[] decryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext); //this line throws exception
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if key and IV are identical during encryption and decryption?

Comment: @Topaco yeah I checked that, they are the same.

Comment: For me, decryption works if the key and IV used in encryption are also used in decryption. It is rather likely that the key derivation, in which numerous parameters are involved, and/or the IV derivation gives different values in both codes.

Comment: Post sample data and add all the missing methods so that the codes are executable and the problem is reproducible, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I checked again if the key and IV are the same as @Topaco suggested and the key was not in fact the same. The thing is, I need for my purposes 128 bit keys and I trimmed the userKey **after** I put it in ukeyString.
So the problem was in the key, really stupid mistake but thanks @Topaco for pointing me to the solution.